# how to upload deb files to launchpad?

Tags: launchpad

I want to upload files on launchpad.
I have tried the help method of launchpad but I couldn't understand.
Please tell me the method, how to upload?
Please don't give me any links to read, just tell me method.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use a PPA, then there is no way to upload your `.deb` files directly. What you have to do is to upload your source package files and launchpad will take care of uploading the binary package files in a controlled environment for security reasons. This also has the advantage that binary packages for all supported architectures will be generated.

If you want just to make a `.deb` file available in launchpad without using a PPA and you already have a project, you need to create a milestone, work on the bugs you want to fix and create a release when you're done. Once the release is created, you can upload all the files you need and they will available in the downloads section of your project.

Comment: Actually I want to upload any file like: Ubuntu Themes, Softwares etc and want to make PPA of them.
Please tell me how to upload themes, files, source codes, etc to launchpad.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot explain that without any link as required in the question.

Comment: what kind of links should I post?

Comment: @Umair there's really no way to do this without [reading this documentation](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA) and uploading source packages.

Comment: I have done Everything.

Comment: Now tell me. How to upload using ftp and what is dput?

Comment: how to use this?

dput ppa:your-lp-id/ppa <source.changes>

Comment: @UmairRiaz For the benefit of other people that migh have the same problem in the future, please don't use comments to ask new questions. Just ask a new question.